# Android, can't make text vertically center in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a problem with making  verticaly center text in TextView.
Android Studio in preview showing text correctly, in center like I want:
[image]

But when I will put app to device (Htc One m8, Android 6) then text is bottom (not in center of orange box (I set TextView to orange for better see where is problem).
[image]

Below text of xml layout, can see find where is a problem? ( I removed part of code, just added main relative and linear and line where is a problem)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="@dimen/main_relative_layout_height_medium"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/main_relative_layout_margin_medium"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:background="@color/widget_relative_layout_background_color"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/main_relative_padding_top_medium">

<!--android:updatePeriodMillis="86400"-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/main_linear_layout_padding_medium"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/main_linear_layout_padding_top_medium"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/main_linear_layout_padding_bottom_medium"
    android:background="@color/widget_linear_layout_background_color"
    android:weightSum="15"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    ...

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="0dp">

         <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/times_row_size_medium"
            android:paddingTop="0dp">


             <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width_size_medium"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/firstWidgetImageView"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_time_to_departure_white"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="02:41"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:textColor="@color/widgetTextColor"
                    android:id="@+id/firstTimeTextView"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/first_time_text_size_medium"
                    android:background="@color/application_button_color" />

            </LinearLayout>

            ...

        </LinearLayout> 
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `center_horizontal` in your TextView change it to `center` and you should be fine.

Code example:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="02:41"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:textColor="@color/widgetTextColor"
    android:id="@+id/firstTimeTextView"
    android:textSize="@dimen/first_time_text_size_medium"
    android:background="@color/application_button_color" />
```

Comment: Thanks HuskyHuskie I tried it but not working. I had to change parent LinearLayout to: Height and width to wrap content also added gravity and layoutGravity to center. Space between text and border I deleted by layout_markingTop=-5dip and layout_marginBottom=-2dip

Answer (score 0):

```
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="02:41"
       android:layout_column="0"
       android:textColor="@color/widgetTextColor"
       android:id="@+id/firstTimeTextView"
       android:textSize="@dimen/first_time_text_size_medium"
       android:background="@color/application_button_color" />
```

Please take a look at the above code . You need to replace gravity from center_horizontal to center .